# What's the relationship between irreducible number and prime number and query common example

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers

I see from textbook that prime number must be irreducible number and not vice versa. But my degree of awareness is limitted in number field, so it's hard to understand because irreducible number is equivalent to prime number in number field. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: In some number fields there are irreducibles which are not prime. These two notions are equivalent exactly when you have uniqueness of "prime factorization" (it should be called "factorization into irreducibles").

Comment: @Crostul, I believe that it is true for GCD domains, which are a slight generalization of UFDs. The reason why this is "close" to your answer is that UFDs are those GCD domains for which irreducible factorizations always exist for non-zero elements.

Answer (score 2):

More accurately, the concept of "prime" is not equivalent to the concept of "irreducible". Irrreduciblity is a *generalization* of primality, every prime is irreducible, but it is possible in some algebraic structures that an irreducible element is not prime. The trouble is, in *some* algebraic structures, they ARE equivalent (most importantly, unique factorization domains).

The definition of irreducible:

If $a = bc \implies b$ or $c$ is a unit.

The definition of prime:

$p|bc \implies p|b$ or $p|c$.

A counter-example to: irreducible $\implies$ prime.

Consider $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.

We first claim $3$ is irreducible. To do this, we introduce the norm function:

$N(a + b\sqrt{-5}) = a^2 + 5b^2$.

It can be shown (I urge you to do this), that:

if $u = a+b\sqrt{-5}, v = c + d\sqrt{-5}$, that $N(uv) = N(u)N(v)$.

Also, if $u \neq \pm 1$, then $N(u) \geq 4$ (why?).

If $u$ is to be a unit, so it has an inverse $u^{-1}$, we have:

$1 = N(1) = N(uu^{-1}) = N(u)N(u^{-1})$. So a unit has to have a norm of $1$, since the norm is a positive integer. Thus the only units are $\pm 1$.

Now $N(3) = 9$, so if we have a factorization of $3$ into non-units, say:

$3 = xy$, then we must have $N(ax) = N(by) = 3$. But no element of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ has a norm of $3$ (see above).

Now $9 = (2 + \sqrt{-5})(2 - \sqrt{-5})$, and $3|9$, but $3\not\mid(2 + \sqrt{-5})$ and $3\not\mid(2-\sqrt{-5})$, so $3$ is not prime.